# Best way to list a Merb::Slices dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, slice, merb

I'm creating a list of the Slices in my Merb app, like this:

> Merb::Slices.each_slice do |slice|

I'd like to get the list of dependencies for each of this slice, any idea how to access it?

I'm still reading merb code, solution might come soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

Seems impossible to get list of dependencies for a particular slice.

The next solution is to parse the slice init.rb

Something interesting found in the quest, the global list of dependencies:

> Merb::BootLoader::Dependencies.dependencies

Comment: You may want to check the Merb IRC channel on freenode, someone there probably knows.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used slices yet, but from my understanding they are like a mini merb app in themself, therefore wouldn't each slice have a `/config/dependencies.rb`? Maybe this gets parsed into the program and is available somewhere.

There may be something [here in the docs](http://merbivore.com/documentation/1.1.0/doc/rdoc/stack/index.html?a=M000823&name=dependencies).

Also, here are the methods available on the Merb constant (which you get things like the environment from). There's one called dependencies which returns an array (which is empty when I'm running with `merb -i` in an app).

```
>> Merb.methods.sort
=> ["<", "<=", "<=>", "==", "===", "=~", ">", ">=", "JSON", "__caller_info__", "__caller_lines__", "__id__", "__profile__", "__send__", "abstract_method", "adapter", "adapter=", "add_generators", "add_mime_type", "add_rakefiles", "ancestors", "args_and_options", "assigns", "at_exit", "at_exit_procs", "autoload", "autoload?", "available_accepts", "available_mime_types", "b64encode", "blank?", "bundled?", "class", "class_eval", "class_variable_defined?", "class_variables", "clone", "config", "const_defined?", "const_get", "const_missing", "const_set", "constants", "context", "debugger", "decode64", "decode_b", "deep_clone", "deferred_actions", "dependencies", "dependency", "describe", "dir_for", "disable", "disabled?", "disabled_components", "disabled_components=", "display", "dup", "encode64", "encoded_hash", "enforce!", "enum_for", "env", "env?", "environment", "environment=", "environment_info", "environment_info=", "eql?", "equal?", "exception", "exiting", "exiting=", "extend", "extract_options_from_args!", "fatal!", "find_const", "forking_environment?", "framework_root", "freeze", "frozen?", "full_const_get", "full_const_set", "generators", "given", "glob_for", "hash", "id", "in?", "include?", "included_modules", "inline", "inspect", "instance_eval", "instance_method", "instance_methods", "instance_of?", "instance_variable_defined?", "instance_variable_get", "instance_variable_set", "instance_variables", "is_a?", "is_haml?", "j", "jj", "kind_of?", "klass_hashes", "klass_hashes=", "load_config", "load_dependencies", "load_dependency", "load_paths", "load_paths=", "log_path", "log_stream", "logger", "make_module", "merb", "merge_env", "meta_class", "method", "method_defined?", "methods", "mime_transform_method", "module_eval", "modules", "name", "nil?", "object_id", "on_jruby?", "on_windows?", "options", "orm", "orm=", "orm_generator_scope", "present?", "print_colorized_backtrace", "private_class_method", "private_instance_methods", "private_method_defined?", "private_methods", "protected_instance_methods", "protected_method_defined?", "protected_methods", "public_class_method", "public_instance_methods", "public_method_defined?", "public_methods", "push_path", "quacks_like?", "rakefiles", "reload", "remove_mime_type", "remove_paths", "rescue_require", "reset_logger!", "respond_to?", "restart_environment", "root", "root=", "root_path", "send", "share_as", "share_examples_for", "shared_examples_for", "should", "should_not", "singleton_methods", "start", "start_environment", "started", "started=", "started?", "taguri", "taguri=", "taint", "tainted?", "template_engine", "template_engine=", "test_framework", "test_framework=", "test_framework_generator_scope", "testing?", "to_a", "to_enum", "to_json", "to_s", "to_yaml", "to_yaml_properties", "to_yaml_style", "track_dependency", "trap", "try_dup", "type", "untaint", "use_orm", "use_template_engine", "use_test", "use_testing_framework", "yaml_as", "yaml_tag_class_name", "yaml_tag_read_class"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory your slice should be bundled up as a gem.  As such, you can pull the dependencies out of the directly from the gem itself